# Unzipping tar.gz file : File too large on aix 7.1

Tags: aix, compression

I am trying to mysql-5.7.18-linux-glibc2.5-x86_64.tar.gz on my aix 7.1 machine.

when i try

`gunzip mysql-5.7.18-linux-glibc2.5-x86_64.tar.gz`

it says file too large.

I also tried

```
gzip -d -c mysql-5.7.18-linux-glibc2.5-x86_64.tar.gz | tar xvf -
```

this tar.gz file is 624mb size. and i have enough space on my disk.

Comment: Are you sure file isn't broken? Check MD5.

Also, try to unzip/untar manually:
`gunzip FILE.tar.gz`
`tar -xvf FILE.tar`

Comment: Does your filesystem support large enough files? JFS can be configured with pretty low limits, and a ~600MiB gzip archive can expand to ~10GiB in certain situations.

Comment: how do i know if my file system supports large files or not? file system is jfs2.

Comment: @sagarlimbu, check this page http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=isg3T1023245

Comment: @sagarlimbu as a start, try this: `gzip -d -c mysql-5.7.18-linux-glibc2.5-x86_64.tar.gz | tar tvf -`

Answer (score 0):

Here's my 2cents:

```
gunzip < remix-v2.0-20170105-pine64-64GB.img.gz > remix-v2.0-20170105-pine64-64GB.img
gunzip < Bliss-pine64_a64+_20170919.img.gz > Bliss-pine64_a64+_20170919.img
```

You will still get `gzip: stdout: File too large` on command line but `img` will extract properly....